# How can filter a timestamp with time zone column using ActiveRecord

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown
>   LINE 1: ...ERE ("transaction_date"=$1) AND ("transaction_date" LIKE $2)
>   ^
>   HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = EpayslipAudit::find()->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC]);

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'transaction_date' => $this->transaction_date,
        ]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'party_id', $this->party_id]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->email]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'period', $this->period]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'status', $this->status]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'action_by', $this->action_by]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'transaction_date', $this->transaction_date]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Comment: update your question and add   a sampe of your input value for search

Comment: By any chance do you have the debugger SQL log? It would be nice to know the values attempted.

Comment: Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown
LINE 1: ...ERE ("transaction_date"=$1) AND ("transaction_date" LIKE $2)
^
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "x_epayslip_audit" WHERE ("transaction_date"='2019-05-29') AND ("transaction_date" LIKE '%2019-05-29%')

Comment: Hi. It seems like you filtered your attribute two times. You should remove this filterWhere: `$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'transaction_date', $this->transaction_date]);`

Comment: i want to filter records which match part of the timestamp like 2019-05-29 in 2019-05-29 23:20:3600 or 23:20 in 2019-05-29 23:20:3600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you shoud use 'OR' statement.

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['or', [
   ['transaction_date' => $this->transaction_date],
   ['LIKE', 'transaction_date', $this->transaction_date]
]]);
```

Or enjoy 'BETWEEN' statement, it can be declared same way.